# Random Data Partionning and range scan

Tags: hbase

Cause HBase just have an orderPartionner, Is there a way to tell to HBase to store data in a random way in order to avoid hotspot but still having the possibility to do range scan based on time?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a order partitioner with salt, added some prefix based on hash value before row key. E.g.

```java
Integer salt = rowKey.hashCode() % numberOfSalts;
Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(salt + "|" + rowKey));
//add some data to you put
...
```

The `numberOfSalts` is treated as numbers of regions involved into bulk write with sequential keys. If, for example, 10 regions can handle your amount of writes, you should use `numberOfRegions` equals to 10 in this formula, or 20 in case if in the future you suggest doubling the number of writes.

After this you can use following code to scan base on range.

```java
 List<Scan> scans = new ArrayList<>();
 for(int salt = 0; salt < numberOfSalts; salt++){
        Scan scan = new Scan();
        scan.setBatch(500);
        scan.setAttribute(Scan.SCAN_ATTRIBUTES_TABLE_NAME, YOUR_TABLE_NAME);
        String salt = StringUtils.leftPad(Integer.toString(i), 3, "0");
        scan.setStartRow( Bytes.toBytes(salt + "|" + scanStart));
        scan.setStartRow( Bytes.toBytes(salt + "|" + scanStop);
        scans.add(scan);
 }

 TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
            scans,
            YourMapper.class,
            Text.class,
            Text.class,
            job);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! your answer is very useful